# Matplotlib Latex troubles

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter notebook to access python. I had many struggles with environments on my MacBook so I deleted all python files on my mac and reinstalled anaconda. In the beginning, it was working, but after mire sophisticated tasks I started receiving strange errors again :(
Here is one of them. I tried to install latex using pip, conda c-forge. The latex module is downloaded in site-packages, however the error is the same.

```py
# %% load libraries
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# %% aesthetics
plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif', size=10)

# %% generate fake data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y0 = np.square(x)
y1 = np.sqrt(x)
y2 = 2 + x

# %% figure

# create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

# parition the figure into 4 subplots with 'gridspec'
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4, # we want 2 rows, 4 cols
                       figure=fig, # this gs applies to figure
                       hspace=0.5, wspace=1, # separation between plots
                       width_ratios=[1, 1, 1, 1], # ration between the
                       # first and second column
                       height_ratios=[1, 1]) # ration between the first ans second row

# add plots
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0:2]) # this will occupy the first row-first colum
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2:4]) # and so on and so forth...
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1:3])

# plot left-top
ax0.plot(x, y0, marker='o', color='green')
ax0.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax0.set_ylabel(r'$x^{2}$')
ax0.grid(ls='--')

# plot right-top
ax1.plot(x, y1, marker='s', color='red')
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\sqrt{x}$')
ax1.grid(ls='--')

# plot middle-bottom
ax2.plot(x, y2, marker='d', color='blue')
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'$2 + x$')
ax2.grid(ls='--')

# save plot
out_f = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'multiple_plots.pdf')
fig.savefig(out_f)

# show plot
plt.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex, cwd)
    251         try:
--> 252             report = subprocess.check_output(
    253                 command, cwd=cwd if cwd is not None else self.texcache,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    414 
--> 415     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    416                **kwargs).stdout

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    492 
--> 493     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    494         try:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1703                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1704                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1705                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/lp/kfk0rkcj6bj31b_4y46369qr0000gn/T/ipykernel_30630/3384632287.py in <module>
     69 # save plot
     70 out_f = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'multiple_plots.pdf')
---> 71 fig.savefig(out_f)
     72 
     73 # show plot

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in savefig(self, fname, transparent, **kwargs)
   3003                 patch.set_edgecolor('none')
   3004 
-> 3005         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   3006 
   3007         if transparent:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2253                 # force the figure dpi to 72), so we need to set it again here.
   2254                 with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
-> 2255                     result = print_method(
   2256                         filename,
   2257                         facecolor=facecolor,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1667             kwargs.pop(arg)
   1668 
-> 1669         return func(*args, **kwargs)
   1670 
   1671     return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    429                          else deprecation_addendum,
    430                 **kwargs)
--> 431         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    432 
    433     return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py in print_pdf(self, filename, dpi, bbox_inches_restore, metadata)
   2723                 RendererPdf(file, dpi, height, width),
   2724                 bbox_inches_restore=bbox_inches_restore)
-> 2725             self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2726             renderer.finalize()
   2727             if not isinstance(filename, PdfPages):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     72     @wraps(draw)
     73     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 74         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     75         if renderer._rasterizing:
     76             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2778 
   2779             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 2780             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   2781                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2782 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    429                          else deprecation_addendum,
    430                 **kwargs)
--> 431         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    432 
    433     return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2919             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2920 
-> 2921         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2922 
   2923         renderer.close_group('axes')

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1135 
   1136         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
-> 1137         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1138                                                                 renderer)
   1139 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1061     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1062         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1063         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1064                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1065                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1061     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1062         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1063         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1064                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1065                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    901 
    902         with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
--> 903             bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    904             x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    905             x, y = self.get_transform().transform((x, y))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    304 
    305         # Full vertical extent of font, including ascenders and descenders:
--> 306         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    307             "lp", self._fontproperties,
    308             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_pdf_ps.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
     86             texmanager = self.get_texmanager()
     87             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
---> 88             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
     89                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
     90             return w, h, d

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    397         else:
    398             # use dviread.
--> 399             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    400             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    401                 page, = dvi

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    289             # and thus replace() works atomically.
    290             with TemporaryDirectory(dir=Path(dvifile).parent) as tmpdir:
--> 291                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    292                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
    293                      texfile], tex, cwd=tmpdir)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex, cwd)
    254                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    255         except FileNotFoundError as exc:
--> 256             raise RuntimeError(
    257                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
    258                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex, cwd)
    251         try:
--> 252             report = subprocess.check_output(
    253                 command, cwd=cwd if cwd is not None else self.texcache,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    414 
--> 415     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    416                **kwargs).stdout

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    492 
--> 493     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    494         try:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1703                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1704                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1705                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    251 
    252     if 'png' in formats:
--> 253         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    254     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    255         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    135         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    136 
--> 137     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    138     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    139     if fmt == 'svg':

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2228                        else suppress())
   2229                 with ctx:
-> 2230                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2231 
   2232             if bbox_inches:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     72     @wraps(draw)
     73     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 74         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     75         if renderer._rasterizing:
     76             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2778 
   2779             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 2780             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   2781                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2782 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    429                          else deprecation_addendum,
    430                 **kwargs)
--> 431         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    432 
    433     return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2919             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2920 
-> 2921         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2922 
   2923         renderer.close_group('axes')

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1135 
   1136         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
-> 1137         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1138                                                                 renderer)
   1139 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1061     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1062         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1063         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1064                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1065                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1061     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1062         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1063         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1064                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1065                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    901 
    902         with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
--> 903             bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    904             x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    905             x, y = self.get_transform().transform((x, y))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    304 
    305         # Full vertical extent of font, including ascenders and descenders:
--> 306         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    307             "lp", self._fontproperties,
    308             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    227             texmanager = self.get_texmanager()
    228             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
--> 229             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
    230                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    231             return w, h, d

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    397         else:
    398             # use dviread.
--> 399             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    400             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    401                 page, = dvi

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    289             # and thus replace() works atomically.
    290             with TemporaryDirectory(dir=Path(dvifile).parent) as tmpdir:
--> 291                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    292                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
    293                      texfile], tex, cwd=tmpdir)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/dataviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex, cwd)
    254                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    255         except FileNotFoundError as exc:
--> 256             raise RuntimeError(
    257                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
    258                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Comment: Numerous similar questions have been raised in SO, so try searching for them as [follows](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+matplotlib+Failed+to+process+string+with+tex+because+latex+could+not+be+found&oq=python+matplotlib+Failed+to+process+string+with+tex+because+latex+could+not+be+found&aqs=chrome..69i57.7167j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Downloading MacTex solved this issue